# Merge sub-regions of multiple regions

Tags: r, sf

First, let's set up the data. Download adjoining Seoul, Incheon, Gyeonggi-do region shapefiles from [this website](http://data.nsdi.go.kr/dataset/15144) (in Korean). I [attach the files](http://www.filedropper.com/koreasca), as they are not accessible outside Korea. Then read into R, name, and combine ([credit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361413/88704)):

```
library(sf)

#Read, name and combine regions
sca_nsdi <- rbind(cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_11.shp"), Name="Seoul"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_28.shp"), Name="Incheon"), 
                  cbind(st_read("LARD_ADM_SECT_SGG_41.shp"), Name="Gyeonggi-do"))

#Plotting reveals sub-regions (the legend was natively clipped)
plot(sca_nsdi[, "Name"])
```

[image]

I wish to merge the sub-regions of these 3 regions. I have tried applying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49354480/7114709), but without success:

```
library(dplyr)

sca_nsdi <- sca_nsdi %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(geometry=st_union(geometry)) %>% 
  ungroup()

plot(sca_nsdi[, "Name"])
```

[image]
The sub-regions are imperfectly merged. (For some reason, the bounding box is also shrunk to the size of Seoul.)

Comment: Someone more savvy might come up with a full solution, but I usually come across this problem when the polygons are not perfectly aligned to start with (tiny gaps along the boundaries). You could try `ms_dissolve` from the rmapshaper package with the `snap = TRUE` argument, which corrects these to some degree. (And use `field = "Name"` to get the grouping you require.)

Comment: @SandyAB `snap` appears to be insufficient in this case. Most sub-regions are not dissolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution to dissolving problems is usually to find a set of pre-dissolved borders. Do they exist?

These borders have a lot of digitising errors if they are supposed to represent a division into contiguous areas.

Using QGIS its easy to zoom into your data and see what's happening. Here's an area where three features all overlap and cross with about a width of 20m:

[image]

and here's a massive gap of about 170 metres width:

[image]

and there are slivers everywhere:

[image]

My usual go-to tool for fixing these things is a standalone programme called `pprepair` https://github.com/tudelft3d/pprepair - there is some work on implementing this within R but I don't think its there yet.

Otherwise the trick is to buffer the polygons so they overlap, then do the union. Given your workflow I would buffer then union the three individual area objects first, then perhaps apply a negative buffer to shrink each one back, and only then combine them into a single object. This way you can tailor the buffer size for each of the three regions.

A quick test shows a 40m buffer works pretty well.

[image]

I don't understand why the bounding box is going wrong but I suspect its the grouped object only taking the extent of the first (or last?) group it processes... possible bug..

The `pprepair` process does a good job of fixing all this once you get the parameters correct. If you try this approach and struggle start a new question and ask.

Comment: `st_buffer` also expands the outer boundary of the region so is the solution to `st_buffer` a second time but negatively? Rather than increasing buffer size, is there not a function to clean up the inside of a boundary?

Comment: Yes, you can do a negative buffer if you think extending your boundary by 20m is going to significantly affect your results. You won't get the *exact* same boundary back though since negative buffering doesn't precisely reverse positive buffering.

Comment: I don't know of an R function that will clean up boundaries, and I don't know a better standalone cleanup program than `pprepair`. If anyone does they can add an answer here.

Comment: I have since found another solution to a very similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548332/hot-to-get-clean-polygons-in-r-after-st-combine-st-union-with-sf-package.

Comment: I've given up trying to install `pprepair` in Windows, but I've achieved reasonably good results with the buffer method. Inclusions remain, which I guess have to be removed manually through QGIS. Technically, the answer is not complete, but I've marked it as the solution anyway (and am very grateful to @Spacedman for even a partial solution).